# setVisibility of an ImageView differently inside different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

The app I'm currently developing has a tabbed view with two fragments each containing a card view inside recycler view.
Now, there is an image view inside the card view that I want to be visible inside fragment1 but not fragment2. But I'm unable to achieve so.
The code I've been trying inside the RecyclerView adapter is-

```
 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_event, parent, false);
    FragmentManager manager = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment1 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.TabFragment1);
    if(fragment1!= null){
        image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

image_view which is inside card_event (CardView) is originally invisible and I only want it to be visible in TabFragment1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, but you are missing the `else` block on your condition. Try replacing

```
Fragment fragment1 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.TabFragment1);
if(fragment1!= null){
    image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

with

```
Fragment fragment1 = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.TabFragment1);
if(fragment1!= null){
    image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

As for the reason - `RecyclerView` does exactly what its name suggests - it recycles views :-D Therefore, each item view if created once and put inside a `ViewHolder`, and you are supposed to adjust it for each item in the list.

What that means is not only that you need to put state in it, but also remove/hide any state that was set to it curing previous binds.

Comment: Thanks, but on adding the else statement the app stopped working and I got a nullPointerException error because of it :/

Comment: also update the question and add the code where you initialize the image_view that you change visibility